# Equals sign is always highlighted white in PrismJS

Tags: nuxt.js, prismjs

I am setting up Prism Codeblocks in my Nuxt Content Project and everything seems to be going well except that my "=" symbols have a semi-transparent white background and I cannot figure out why. I have tried different themes thinking it was an issue with my styling but even when I copy/paste themes from a repo ([like this one](https://github.com/PrismJS/prism-themes)) I still see the same thing:

[image]

I just downloaded the default package from Prism's website and am just using plain themes.

What might be happening here?

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are only using a single theme's css.

This generally happens when you include the css file for both the default theme, as well as another theme. For example, if you have `prism.min.css` and `prism-twilight.min.css` it will cause the issue you are having. It can seem like themes build upon the default `prism.min.css` file, but instead, they conflict with one another.